# Non-overlapping ridgeline plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, iris-dataset, ridgeline-plot

Hi everyone I was looking at some ridgeline plots in R, more specifically in the post "Introduction to ggridges", and my goal is to make this plot but without the overlap:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - stat(ecdf)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Tail probability", direction = -1)
```

By reading the same post, the overlap can be added with:

```
+ geom_density_ridges(scale = 0.9)
```

but for some reason I got this error:

```
Error in 0.5 - ecdf : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thank you

Comment: Follow this article :The grouping aesthetic does not need to be provided if a categorical variable is mapped onto the y axis, but it does need to be provided if the variable is numerical. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: So you need transform categorical variable to numeric value. you can see example this article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the dsired result get rid of the second `geom_density_ridges` (this caused the error) and simply add `scale = 0.9` to the first layer:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - stat(ecdf)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE, scale = 0.9) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Tail probability", direction = -1)
#> Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
```

[image]